# Relocate Eclipse on Mac

Tags: macos, eclipse

I've rather daftly been using Eclipse IDE from an install location on an External Hard Drive as initially I wasn't going to be keeping this particular laptop.

How do I move the install from the external hard drive into my Applications folder, I've tried relocating the directory but I suspect that apps are actually installed elsewhere and shortcuts are created to the app within the Applications folder.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually eclipse is installed by just unzipping an archive in a single folder. You can freely move it anywhere (as in `/Application`) without any problem.

Comment: From the install location I used 'cp -R eclipse/ /Applications' and it worked a treat. Thank you. I think I'd been missing the recursive option when trying previously

Answer (score 1):

proceed to the terminal and type:

```
sudo find / -name 'eclipse'
```

The results of all possible directories and files with the name 'eclipse' will be found.